# Trying to understand basic integrals from a video of 3Blue1Brown

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, area

I stumbled on a 3Blue1Brown video on calculus. I ask here because in the video no one will answer and I've been trying for a while to solve this doubt.

Here's [the video at the right time](https://youtu.be/WUvTyaaNkzM?list=PLZHQObOWTQDMsr9K-rj53DwVRMYO3t5Yr&t=808).

What I don't understand is why is he using $A(3.001)$, or what does it mean the change of the output between those two points, and that that is approx. $9$? meaning if we take the area at
$$
\frac{A(3.001)}{0.001} - \frac{A(3)}{0.001} 
$$
we get a "small square" which is the "part that we add" to $A(3)$ to make it $A(3.001)$, (we subtracted the "taller" rectangle of $A(3.001)$ from the "smaller rectangle" of $A(3)$).

What does it mean that this "tiny square" is equal two $9$? it cant be the area of $A(3)$, clearly, since it equals $x^2$. Considering the formula and the logic there, I would expect a calculation of $A(3)/0.001 = 9$, because $A(3) = 9 \cdot 0.001$. I don't see from where does the $A(3.001)/0.001$ come from.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's 3Blue1Brown.

Comment: $A(3)$ is the area under $y=x^2$ from $x=0$ to $x=3$. $A(3)/0.001 \ne 9$, and I don't think looking at $A(3)/0.001$ alone (instead of $[A(3.001)-A(3)]/0.001$ as a whole) is helpful.

Comment: @peterwhy if its the area from 0 to 3, then why would the base be 0.001 and not 3?

Comment: $A(3)$ is the area from $0$ to $3$, but the numerator from the video ($A(3.001)-A(3)$) is the area from $3$ to $3.001$. I think considering the division of area $A(3.001)-A(3)$ by the width $0.001$ would be more helpful than considering $A(3)/0.001$ alone.

Comment: @peterwhy I actually did it on purpose, the subtraction of the 2 divisions, to underline the fact that its the area of A(3) and the area of A(3.001) at a fixed rate of change, meaning with a fixed length for the base, therefore A(3) its not the area from 0 to 3, but rather the area from 3 to 3.001, and A(3.001) is the area from 3.001 to 3.002.
Otherwise if it was like you said they wouldn't have a common denominator.

Comment: I was merely describing what $A(3)$ and $A(3.001)$ mean according to the video.

Answer (score 2):

You will not get a good intuition by writing the formula
$$ \frac{A(3.001)}{0.001} - \frac{A(3)}{0.001}. $$

Notice that this is **not** what is shown in the video. What is shown in the video is
$$
\frac{A(3.001) - A(3)}{0.001}.
$$

[image]

This formula has two main parts. One part is $A(3.001) - A(3)$.
The geometric significance of this is that $A(3.001)$ is the entire area under the curve between $0$ and the line $x = 3.001$,
while $A(3)$ is the area under the curve between $0$ and the line $x = 3$.

You can confirm that these are the correct definitions of $A(3)$ and $A(3.001)$ by listening to the video starting at 10:26. Try it with closed captions on for extra clarity. It says:

> Are you able to find a function $A(x)$ that gives you the area under this parabola between $0$ and $x$?

So when $x = 3$, then $A(x) = A(3)$ is the area under the parabola between $0$ and $3$, not between $3$ and $3.001$.

The region with area $A(3.001)$ is subdivided by the line $x = 3$ into two parts:
one part is the region with area $A(3)$, and the other part is a region between the lines $x = 3$ and $x = 3.001$.

Let $\Delta$ be the area of the region between $x = 3$ and $x = 3.001$.
Then $A(3.001) = A(3) + \Delta$, because there is a region of area $A(3.001)$ that can be subdivided exactly into two regions, one of area $A(3)$ and one of area $\Delta$.
Therefore
$$ A(3.001) - A(3) = \Delta. $$

The region between $x = 3$ and $x = 3.001$ is approximately a rectangle with height
$3^2 = 9$ and width $0.001$.
(Only approximately a rectangle, because the boundary at the top of that region follows the curve, which is not horizontal.)
So $\Delta$ is approximately the area of that rectangle,
$$ \Delta \approx 3^2 \times 0.001. $$

Now we can replace $\Delta$ by $A(3.001) - A(3)$, because $ A(3.001) - A(3) = \Delta.$
$$ A(3.001) - A(3) \approx 3^2 \times 0.001. $$

Now divide both sides by $0.001$:
$$ \frac{A(3.001) - A(3)}{0.001} \approx 3^2. $$

That is how $0.001$ is introduced into the formula.
It is not related to $A(3.001)$ individually, nor is it related to $A(3)$ individually.
It is related specifically to the narrow yellow strip in the diagram, labeled $dA$,
whose area is $A(3.001) - A(3)$.

The formula $ \frac{A(3.001) - A(3)}{0.001} \approx 3^2 $
simply reflects the fact that you can find the height of a rectangle
by taking the area of the rectangle and dividing by the width of the rectangle.

Comment: I actually did it on purpose, the subtraction of the 2 divisions, to underline the fact that its the area of A(3) and the area of A(3.001) at a fixed rate of change, meaning with a fixed length for the base, therefore A(3) its not the area from 0 to 3, but rather the area from 3 to 3.001, and A(3.001) is the area from 3.001 to 3.002. Otherwise if it was like you said they wouldn't have a common denominator.

Comment: No no no no no. Everything you wrote in that comment is wrong, especially the part about $A(3)$ being the area from $3$ to $3.001$. Again, $A(3)$ can only be the area from $0$ to $3$, which is why the arrow from $A(x)$ points into the interior of a large region under the curve. Try watching the video more carefully. Until you understand the correct definition of $A(x)$, it will make no sense at all.

Comment: I have found the exact place in the video where $A(x)$ is defined and added the definition to the answer so that you can understand better.